# How to restructure this form to create association the other way around?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, associations

Initially I created Exercises to browse. Then I added the ability to record "log_entries" against them.

This works for that

```
  = semantic_form_for @exercise do |exercise|
    = exercise.semantic_fields_for :log_entries do |log_entry|
      = render 'log_entries/log_entry_fields', :f => log_entry
    .links
      = link_to_add_association 'Add Set', exercise, :log_entries, :partial => "log_entries/log_entry_fields", :data => {:role => "button", :icon => "plus"}
    = exercise.buttons do
      = exercise.commit_button "Apply", :button_html => {:data => {:icon => "check", :theme => "b"}}
      = link_to "Cancel", "", :data => {:rel => "back", :icon => "delete", :role => "button", :theme => "a"}
```

I now added the requirement of needing it to be associated to a user. I'm not sure how to do that in the best manner. This is posting to the exercise controller now, and an exercise isn't really associated with a user. So in the exercise controller I could merge the params in, but that seems hackish.

The proper way would be to create the log entry association through the user, right? But how would I restructure the form to make that work?

I probably shouldn't be using the exercise controller anymore either for that since it's creating log_entries, and then in the LogEntryController the user can be set through there... but what's the best way to do this? For some reason I can't figure out how to pass in the workout to the log_entries controller and then have the collection render in the form like shown.

Maybe I'm brain pooped from coding all day. Thanks!

I'm using the [Cocoon](https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon) library for the add association functionality.

Comment: I realized I can't even set the user through the Exercise controller because I'd have to iterate over the collection of logentries and that's lame to add in a user_id for each one. So, how to do this the other way around? Create the collection through log_entries controller and set the user and exercise through there?

Comment: Well, it depends on how you want your user to behave: do you want to be able to assign these `log_entries` to users, or do you want them assigned to a logged in user. For the first use-case, see anxiety's answer, for the second you should put assign the user to the log_entry based on the `current_user` (if you use Devise) or something, but you wouldn't want to do it through a REST-path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a gem to accomplish this. Consider the following associations:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :log_entries
end

class Exercise < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :log_entries
end

class LogEntry < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :exercise
end
```

And the following deeply-nested routes:

```
YourApp::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :users do
    resources :exercises do
      resources :log_entries
    end
  end
end
```

Which would result in a new link looking like this (long, I know):

```
<%= link_to new_user_exercise_log_entry_path(user, exercise) %>
```

where `user` and `exercise` are the user and exercise objects that the `log_entry` will belong to. The resource part of your URI would look something like this, for example:

```
/users/1/exercises/1/log_entries/new
```

Note, that it's the log_entry form that you should be submitting, not the exercise form.

And you wouldn't have to do anything special with your log_entry form. Since the relations exist between the models and the routes are nested, you can simply access the `params[:user_id]` and `params[:exercise_id]` in your `log_entry` controller action and assign them to your new `log_entry` object there.

Comment: Hi, thank you. So, I was wondering if you could help me out a little further. This is starting to make more sense. The problem is that I add multiple log entries in one form (using cocoon). So using the above example, how would I do it in a form state? E.g: semantic_form_for [user, exercise] (how do log entries get put into that path?)

Comment: I was able to do it with  

= semantic_form_for [current_user, ew.exercise] do |exercise|

And yadayadada which goes to exercises_controller and does this `    params[:exercise][:log_entries_attributes].each do |value|
      value[1].merge!(:user_id => current_user.id)
    end`

So if I can make this go through log_entries I won't have ugly code yay. Figuring that out now.